# JOGL Animation Problems

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl

I was learning to use JOGL and I ran into a problem when following this tutorial:

- https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-1
- https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-2
- https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-3

When running the code on the third tutorial I saw a triangle as expected but it wasn't moving. I also got this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Drawable already added to animator: com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator[started false, animating false, paused false, drawable 1, totals[dt 0, frames 0, fps 0.0], modeBits 1, init'ed true, animThread null, exclCtxThread false(null)], AWT-GLCanvas[Realized true,
    jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsOnscreenWGLDrawable,
    Factory   jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLDrawableFactory@1e71839,
    handle    0x0,
    Drawable size 292x273,
    AWT pos 4/23, size 292x273,
    visible true, displayable true,
    AWTGraphicsConfiguration[AWTGraphicsScreen[AWTGraphicsDevice[type .awt, connection \Display1, unitID 0, awtDevice D3DGraphicsDevice[screen=1], handle 0x0], idx 1],
    chosen    GLCaps[wgl vid 0x7 arb: rgba 8/8/8/0, trans-rgba 0x0/0/0/0, accum-rgba 16/16/16/16, dp/st/ms 24/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL4bc/GL4bc.hw], on-scr[.]],
    requested GLCaps[rgba 8/8/8/0, opaque, accum-rgba 0/0/0/0, dp/st/ms 16/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL4bc/GL4bc.hw], on-scr[.]],
    sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig@300ca7[dev=D3DGraphicsDevice[screen=1],pixfmt=7],
    encapsulated WindowsWGLGraphicsConfiguration[DefaultGraphicsScreen[WindowsGraphicsDevice[type .windows, connection decon, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner false, NullToolkitLock[]], idx 1], pfdID 7, ARB-Choosen true,
    requested GLCaps[rgba 8/8/8/0, opaque, accum-rgba 0/0/0/0, dp/st/ms 16/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL4bc/GL4bc.hw], on-scr[.]],
    chosen    GLCaps[wgl vid 0x7 arb: rgba 8/8/8/0, trans-rgba 0x0/0/0/0, accum-rgba 16/16/16/16, dp/st/ms 24/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL4bc/GL4bc.hw], on-scr[.]]]]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.add(AnimatorBase.java:183)
    at SimpleScene.main(SimpleScene.java:33)
```

On the first part of the tutorial when setting up my class path I found the `jogl-all.jar` and `gluegen.jar` but I couldn't find the `nativewindow.all.jar` or `newt.all.jar` so I choose the closest I could find which were `jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar` and `newt-natives-windows-amd64.jar`.(I don't even think I need newt because I think that just allows me to use other types of frames besides the standard AWT frame. Correct me if I'm wrong.) Could this have anything to do with the problem?

Answer (score 7):

In the tutorial, it looks like "animator.add(canvas);" is redundant.  Just comment it out.

```
Animator animator = new Animator(canvas);
// animator.add(canvas);
animator.start();
```